# Recognize software since hard drive lettre shift

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have a problem since I have changed the letter of my hard drive.

Softwares are installed on this hard drive. So, I changed the link of the shortcut and I can launch all software . But for the windows 7 these softwares are deleted - in the settings>when I check on uninstall software> there is a message which tells that the software are uninstalled (manually).

How I can fix the problem without uninstall all software and re-install ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it an option to just set the drive letter back to its original value?

Comment: I'd rather not to

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately the expected behaviour when you change the drive letter of a volume with registered programs installed on it.
The programs will have more than just shortcuts to them which depend on the drive letter. For example, when Microsoft Office gets installed to C:\Program Files, many keys in the registry will be written, with that location on disk as the location of Microsoft Office. Eg: *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\InstallRoot* will have a value called *Path* which points to *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\*.
Once you change the drive letter, so C: becomes, for example, X:, the data in the registry is no longer correct. You might also have problems with your environment variables. If *%SystemDrive%* is still showing as *C:* (and *%ProgramFiles%* as *C:\Program Files*), and you change the drive letter, that's going to break a lot of stuff.
You could search through the registry and look for instances of "C:\" and change it to "X:\" (if C: is the old letter, and X: the new letter), and make sure your environment variables are pointing to the right disk.
Alternatively, you can use the *subst* command, so you have two drive letters pointing to the same disk.
For example, running **subst C: X:\** would create a drive C:, which is actually the same thing as drive X:. You would be able to use either to access the files.
If you want to fix the issue of software appearing to have already been removed manually, you might be able to do this by looking at the keys under **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**, and updating any values called **InstallSource**, **InstallLocation**, **DisplayIcon**, or **UninstallString** which reference the old drive letter.